Azure Data Factory: Error "Input column 'ColumnName' in mapping cannot be found" after closing data flow
I am encountering an issue in Azure Data Factory (ADF) where after I close the data flow and try to run the pipeline, my data flow loses it's setting for a few input column mappings.
Setup:

I’ve created a pipeline that executes a data flow.
The Source in the data flow reads multiple JSON files with a similar structure, and the Sink writes the data to a SQL Server table.
I’ve imported the schema projection in the Source tab and manually mapped the fields in the Sink Mapping tab.
After this, I published the pipeline and ran it successfully, with data loading correctly into the SQL Server table.

Problem:
After everything is published, when I close the data flow and pipeline and reopen the pipeline:

Running the pipeline results in the error: "Input column 'ColumnName' in mapping cannot be found."
The mappings are not deleted, and when I check the Sink Mapping tab, all the fields are still mapped correctly — nothing appears to be wrong.
However, I have to manually reselect the same input columns in the Sink Mapping tab and essentially "remap" them again, even though they appear correctly mapped. After reselecting and publishing again, the pipeline runs without issues.
The problem reoccurs every time I close the data flow and after that try to run the pipeline.

What I’ve Tried:

Re-importing the schema projection in the Source tab.
Remapping the fields in the Sink Mapping tab.
Debugging the pipeline, saving the mappings, and republishing.

What I Need Help With:

Why do I keep getting the error "Input column 'ColumnName' in mapping cannot be found" after closing the data flow, even though the mappings are visually correct?
How can I ensure that the mappings are saved and persist after closing the data flow and reopening the pipeline?

Screenshots:

Pipeline is running after remapping and publishing:


Pipeline Error after I close the pipeline and data flow and reopen the pipeline:


Source Projection after I get the error:


Sink Mapping Tab after I get the error:


Manual reselection of the same fields (the issue is temporarily fixed after reselecting the same fields in the Input Columns of the Sink Mapping tab):




please check the below answer and let me know if there are any issues.

I have tried your scenario and got the same error after re-opening the dataflow or pipeline.

The reason for this error using select kind of mapping in the array.

The mapping in the dataflow sink is same as select transformation mapping. Here, when you select an inner object within an array manually, by default it selects the 1st element of the array. The select transformation is mostly used when dealing with complex type of columns. When dealing with array, it doesn't know the inner object but when you specify manually, it will identify at that time and that's why it will give proper result in that pipeline run. But it cannot identify it dynamically might be the reason for this error.
To avoid this error, you can use Derived column transformation. Create the required columns from the JSON array like below.

Go to the sink mapping and remove the extra columns.

Now, it won't give the above error on the validation and will give expected results.

